# Android Textview equally distribute horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I want to display values in listview where all 5 values of row should take equal width and height over all dimensions
 Here is my list_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12.0dip"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But it is not equally distributing horizontally. In preview it is showing 5 rectangular textview but when it comes in listview values over textview will become auto fit so that textview getting shrink.

Comment: let me know why down vote? Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `layout_weight="0.20"` for every `TextView`, meaning every `TextView` will take 20% of space.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="12.0dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="EEEEEEEE"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:text="DDDDDDDDD"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:text="CCCCCCCCCC"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:text="BBBBBBBBBBB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="8.0dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Weight distribution]

Comment: No it's not working. all textview is getting auto-fit so that linerlayout is getting shrink to exact width of total textview.

Comment: I have just tested it, and it does what you want, that all 5 TextView's take equal amount of width?

Comment: I had problem with parent layout where  width and height set like <android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: one thing needed to kept in mind : "layout_width" need to be taken as "0dp" for this to work

Answer (score 2):

Try adding weightSum to linearLayout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="12.0dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

layout weight should work, try removing gravity attribute for your Textview. if still not working, play with weightSum, set weightSum for your LinearLayout and distribute that to TextViews

ex :

```
<LinearLayout
...
... 
android:weightSum="5">

  <TextView
  .. 
  .. 
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
  .. 
  .. 
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
  .. 
  .. 
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
  .. 
  .. 
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
  .. 
  .. 
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this might work.